# Java Swing Version of ControlsFx ListSelection View

Tags: java, swing, jlist, controlsfx

I am looking for a Java Swing Version of 2 JLists that interact with one another.  An "available" list and a "selected" list.  You can move elements from one list to the other.  I also would like to be able to move items in the "selected" list up and down...

Answer (score 0):

Been looking all over for this and couldn't find it so I decided to code it myself and share it.. This is a Dual JList which allows moving elements from one to the other via buttons or mouse double click. I used the example [here](http://www.java2s.com/Tutorials/Java/Swing/JList/Create_a_dual_JList_component_in_Java.htm) to come up with the following result. Hope this can help others. If anyone can make it prettier it would be much appreciated.

```
import java.awt.BorderLayout;
import java.awt.Color;
import java.awt.GridBagConstraints;
import java.awt.GridBagLayout;
import java.awt.Insets;
import java.awt.event.ActionEvent;
import java.awt.event.ActionListener;
import java.util.Arrays;
import java.util.Collection;
import java.util.Iterator;
import java.util.Vector;
import java.awt.event.MouseAdapter;
import java.awt.event.MouseEvent;
import javax.swing.ListSelectionModel;
import javax.swing.AbstractListModel;
import javax.swing.BorderFactory;
import javax.swing.JButton;
import javax.swing.JFrame;
import javax.swing.JLabel;
import javax.swing.JList;
import javax.swing.JPanel;
import javax.swing.JScrollPane;
import javax.swing.ListCellRenderer;
import javax.swing.ListModel;

public class DualListBox extends JPanel {

  private static final Insets EMPTY_INSETS = new Insets(0, 0, 0, 0);

    private static final String UP_BUTTON_LABEL = "^";
    private static final String DOWN_BUTTON_LABEL = "v";


  private static final String ADD_BUTTON_LABEL = "Add >";
  private static final String ADD_ALL_BUTTON_LABEL = "Add All >>";

  private static final String REMOVE_BUTTON_LABEL = "< Remove";
  private static final String REMOVE_ALL_BUTTON_LABEL = "<< Remove All";

  private static final String DEFAULT_SOURCE_CHOICE_LABEL = "Available";

  private static final String DEFAULT_DEST_CHOICE_LABEL = "Selected";

  private JLabel sourceLabel;

  private JList sourceList;

  private MyListModel sourceListModel;

  private JList destList;

  private MyListModel destListModel;

  private JLabel destLabel;

  private JButton addButton;

  private JButton removeButton;

  private JButton addAllButton;

  private JButton removeAllButton;

  private JButton upButton;

  private JButton downButton;


  public DualListBox() {
    initScreen();
  }

  public String getSourceChoicesTitle() {
    return sourceLabel.getText();
  }

  public void setSourceChoicesTitle(String newValue) {
    sourceLabel.setText(newValue);
  }

  public String getDestinationChoicesTitle() {
    return destLabel.getText();
  }

  public void setDestinationChoicesTitle(String newValue) {
    destLabel.setText(newValue);
  }

  public void clearSourceListModel() {
    sourceListModel.clear();
  }

  public void clearDestinationListModel() {
    destListModel.clear();
  }

  public void addSourceElements(ListModel newValue) {
    fillListModel(sourceListModel, newValue);
  }

  public void setSourceElements(ListModel newValue) {
    clearSourceListModel();
    addSourceElements(newValue);
  }

  public void addDestinationElements(ListModel newValue) {
    fillListModel(destListModel, newValue);
  }

  private void fillListModel(MyListModel model, ListModel newValues) {
    int size = newValues.getSize();
    for (int i = 0; i < size; i++) {
      model.add(newValues.getElementAt(i));
      System.out.println("adding .."+newValues.getElementAt(i));
    }
  }

  public void addSourceElements(Object newValue[]) {
    fillListModel(sourceListModel, newValue);
  }

  public void setSourceElements(Object newValue[]) {
    clearSourceListModel();
    addSourceElements(newValue);
  }


  public void addDestinationElements(Object newValue[]) {
    fillListModel(destListModel, newValue);
  }




  private void fillListModel(MyListModel model, Object newValues[]) {
    model.addAll(newValues);
  }

  public Iterator sourceIterator() {
    return sourceListModel.iterator();
  }

  public Iterator destinationIterator() {
    return destListModel.iterator();
  }

  public void setSourceCellRenderer(ListCellRenderer newValue) {
    sourceList.setCellRenderer(newValue);
  }

  public ListCellRenderer getSourceCellRenderer() {
    return sourceList.getCellRenderer();
  }

  public void setDestinationCellRenderer(ListCellRenderer newValue) {
    destList.setCellRenderer(newValue);
  }

  public ListCellRenderer getDestinationCellRenderer() {
    return destList.getCellRenderer();
  }

  public void setVisibleRowCount(int newValue) {
    sourceList.setVisibleRowCount(newValue);
    destList.setVisibleRowCount(newValue);
  }

  public int getVisibleRowCount() {
    return sourceList.getVisibleRowCount();
  }

  public void setSelectionBackground(Color newValue) {
    sourceList.setSelectionBackground(newValue);
    destList.setSelectionBackground(newValue);
  }

  public Color getSelectionBackground() {
    return sourceList.getSelectionBackground();
  }

  public void setSelectionForeground(Color newValue) {
    sourceList.setSelectionForeground(newValue);
    destList.setSelectionForeground(newValue);
  }

  public Color getSelectionForeground() {
    return sourceList.getSelectionForeground();
  }

  private void clearSourceSelected() {
    Object selected[] = sourceList.getSelectedValues();
    for (int i = selected.length - 1; i >= 0; --i) {
      sourceListModel.removeElement(selected[i]);
    }
    sourceList.getSelectionModel().clearSelection();
  }

  private void clearDestinationSelected() {
    Object selected[] = destList.getSelectedValues();
    for (int i = selected.length - 1; i >= 0; --i) {
      destListModel.removeElement(selected[i]);
    }
    destList.getSelectionModel().clearSelection();
  }

    private void clearSourceAll() {
    Object selected[] = ((MyListModel)sourceList.getModel()).toArray();
    for (int i = selected.length - 1; i >= 0; --i) {
      sourceListModel.removeElement(selected[i]);
    }
    sourceList.getSelectionModel().clearSelection();
  }

  private void clearDestinationAll() {
    Object selected[] = ((MyListModel)destList.getModel()).toArray();
    for (int i = selected.length - 1; i >= 0; --i) {
      destListModel.removeElement(selected[i]);
    }
    destList.getSelectionModel().clearSelection();
  }




  private void initScreen() {
    setBorder(BorderFactory.createEtchedBorder());
    setLayout(new GridBagLayout());
    sourceLabel = new JLabel(DEFAULT_SOURCE_CHOICE_LABEL);
    sourceListModel = new MyListModel();
    sourceList = new JList(sourceListModel);
    sourceList.addMouseListener(new MouseAdapter() {
         public void mouseClicked(MouseEvent me) {
            if (me.getClickCount() == 2) 
            {
                     addDestinationElements(new Object[] { sourceList.getSelectedValue() });
                     clearSourceSelected();
            }
         }
      });
    add(sourceLabel, new GridBagConstraints(0, 0, 1, 1, 0, 0,
        GridBagConstraints.CENTER, GridBagConstraints.NONE,
        EMPTY_INSETS, 0, 0));
    add(new JScrollPane(sourceList), new GridBagConstraints(0, 1, 1, 5, .5,
        1, GridBagConstraints.CENTER, GridBagConstraints.BOTH,
        EMPTY_INSETS, 0, 0));

    addButton = new JButton(ADD_BUTTON_LABEL);
    add(addButton, new GridBagConstraints(1, 1, 1, 1, 0, .1,
        GridBagConstraints.CENTER, GridBagConstraints.NONE,
        EMPTY_INSETS, 0, 0));
    addButton.addActionListener(new AddListener());


    addAllButton = new JButton(ADD_ALL_BUTTON_LABEL);
    add(addAllButton, new GridBagConstraints(1, 2, 1, 1, 0, .1,
        GridBagConstraints.CENTER, GridBagConstraints.NONE,
        EMPTY_INSETS, 0, 0));
    addAllButton.addActionListener(new AddAllListener());



    removeButton = new JButton(REMOVE_BUTTON_LABEL);
    add(removeButton, new GridBagConstraints(1, 4, 1, 1, 0, .1,
        GridBagConstraints.CENTER, GridBagConstraints.NONE, new Insets(
            0, 5, 0, 5), 0, 0));
    removeButton.addActionListener(new RemoveListener());

    removeAllButton = new JButton(REMOVE_ALL_BUTTON_LABEL);
    add(removeAllButton, new GridBagConstraints(1, 5, 1, 1, 0, .1,
        GridBagConstraints.CENTER, GridBagConstraints.NONE, new Insets(
            0, 5, 0, 5), 0, 0));
    removeAllButton.addActionListener(new RemoveAllListener());



    destLabel = new JLabel(DEFAULT_DEST_CHOICE_LABEL);
    destListModel = new MyListModel();
    destList = new JList(destListModel);
    destList.setSelectionMode(ListSelectionModel.SINGLE_INTERVAL_SELECTION);
        destList.addMouseListener(new MouseAdapter() {
         public void mouseClicked(MouseEvent me) {
            if (me.getClickCount() == 2) 
            {
                     System.out.println("Double clicked on " + destList.getSelectedValue());
                     addSourceElements(new Object[] { destList.getSelectedValue() });
                     clearDestinationSelected();
            }
         }
      });


    add(destLabel, new GridBagConstraints(2, 0, 1, 1, 0, 0,
        GridBagConstraints.CENTER, GridBagConstraints.NONE,
        EMPTY_INSETS, 0, 0));
    add(new JScrollPane(destList), new GridBagConstraints(2, 1, 1, 5, .5,
        1.0, GridBagConstraints.CENTER, GridBagConstraints.BOTH,
        EMPTY_INSETS, 0, 0));


    upButton = new JButton(UP_BUTTON_LABEL) ;
    upButton.addActionListener(new MoveUpListener());
    downButton = new JButton(DOWN_BUTTON_LABEL) ;
    downButton.addActionListener(new MoveDownListener());
    add(upButton, new GridBagConstraints(3, 1, 1, 1, 0, 0,
        GridBagConstraints.CENTER, GridBagConstraints.NONE,
        EMPTY_INSETS, 0, 0));       
    add(downButton, new GridBagConstraints(3, 2, 1, 1, 0, 0,
        GridBagConstraints.CENTER, GridBagConstraints.NONE,
        EMPTY_INSETS, 0, 0));               



  }

  public static void main(String args[]) {
    JFrame f = new JFrame("Dual List Box Tester");
    f.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
    DualListBox dual = new DualListBox();
    dual.addSourceElements(new String[] { "One", "Two", "Three" });
    dual.addSourceElements(new String[] { "Four", "Five", "Six" });
    dual.addSourceElements(new String[] { "Seven", "Eight", "Nine" });
    dual.addSourceElements(new String[] { "Ten", "Eleven", "Twelve" });
    dual
        .addSourceElements(new String[] { "Thirteen", "Fourteen",
            "Fifteen" });
    dual.addSourceElements(new String[] { "Sixteen", "Seventeen",
        "Eighteen" });
    dual.addSourceElements(new String[] { "Nineteen", "Twenty", "Thirty" });
    f.getContentPane().add(dual, BorderLayout.CENTER);
    f.setSize(400, 300);
    f.setVisible(true);
  }

  private class MoveUpListener implements ActionListener {
    public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
      Object selected[] = destList.getSelectedValues();
      int[] selectedindices = destList.getSelectedIndices();



      destListModel.moveUp(selected);
      int[] newselectedindices = new int[selectedindices.length];
      for(int i =0; i <selectedindices.length;i++)
      {
         int oldindex = selectedindices[i];
         if(oldindex != 0)
         {
             newselectedindices[i] = oldindex-1;
         }
      }
      destList.setSelectedIndices(newselectedindices);

    }
  } 

 private class MoveDownListener implements ActionListener {
    public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
      Object selected[] = destList.getSelectedValues();
      int[] selectedindices = destList.getSelectedIndices();



      destListModel.moveDown(selected);
      int[] newselectedindices = new int[selectedindices.length];
      for(int i =0; i <selectedindices.length;i++)
      {
         int oldindex = selectedindices[i];
         if(oldindex != ((MyListModel)destList.getModel()).getSize())
         {
             newselectedindices[i] = oldindex+1;
         }
      }
      destList.setSelectedIndices(newselectedindices);
    }
  } 

  private class AddListener implements ActionListener {
    public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
      Object selected[] = sourceList.getSelectedValues();
      addDestinationElements(selected);
      clearSourceSelected();
    }
  }


   private class AddAllListener implements ActionListener {
    public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
      Object selected[] = ((MyListModel)sourceList.getModel()).toArray();
      addDestinationElements(selected);
      clearSourceAll();
    }
  }

  private class RemoveListener implements ActionListener {
    public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
      Object selected[] = destList.getSelectedValues();
      addSourceElements(selected);
      clearDestinationSelected();
    }
  }

  private class RemoveAllListener implements ActionListener {
    public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
      Object selected[] = ((MyListModel)destList.getModel()).toArray();
      addSourceElements(selected);
      clearDestinationAll();
    }
  }


}

class MyListModel extends AbstractListModel {

  Vector model;

  public MyListModel() {
    model = new Vector();
  }


  public void moveUp(Object[] values)
  {

      for(int i=0; i <values.length; i++)
      {
          int firstindex = model.indexOf(values[i]);
          Object selected = values[i];
          if(firstindex == 0) break;
          else
          {
              Object tempobj = model.get(firstindex-1);
              model.set(firstindex-1,selected);
              model.set(firstindex,tempobj);
              fireContentsChanged(this, 0, getSize());            
          }

      }

  }
 public void moveDown(Object[] values)
  {

    //  for(int i=0; i <values.length; i++)
        for(int i=values.length-1; i >=0; i--)
      {
          int firstindex = model.indexOf(values[i]);
          Object selected = values[i];
          if(firstindex == model.size()-1 ) break;
          else
          {
              Object tempobj = model.get(firstindex+1);
              model.set(firstindex+1,selected);
              model.set(firstindex,tempobj);
              fireContentsChanged(this, 0, getSize());  
          }


      }

  }

  public int getSize() {
    return model.size();
  }

  public Object getElementAt(int index) {
    return model.toArray()[index];
  }

  public void add(Object element) {
    if (model.add(element)) {
      fireContentsChanged(this, 0, getSize());
    }
  }

  public void addAll(Object elements[]) 
  {
    Collection c = Arrays.asList(elements);
    model.addAll(c);
    fireContentsChanged(this, 0, getSize());
  }

  public void clear() {
    model.clear();
    fireContentsChanged(this, 0, getSize());
  }

  public boolean contains(Object element) {
    return model.contains(element);
  }



  public Iterator iterator() {
    return model.iterator();
  }


  public Object[] toArray()
  {
      return model.toArray();
  }

  public boolean removeElement(Object element) {
    boolean removed = model.remove(element);
    if (removed) {
      fireContentsChanged(this, 0, getSize());
    }
    return removed;
  }




}
```